# Solving sparse linear systems in CUDA using LU factorization

Tags: c, cuda

The current MATLAB based C implementation takes around  `6ms`
for solving  `Ax=B`, where  `A` is banded sparse matrix with band-width  `3`
of dimensions  `780 X 780`.

Now I am looking to use  `cuBLAS`/`cuSPARSE` to find a faster solution.
I need to solve  `1440` of such equations in a loop.

I tried using PCG based method but that is very slow and the output is not matching.

**Is there any direct solution using `cuBLAS`/`cuSPARSE` for solving  `Ax=B`?**

Comment: possible duplicate of [Solving Ax=B on GPU](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17697448/solving-ax-b-on-gpu)

Comment: I think the duplicate should be closed, not this one; this is sort of an interesting problem.  The individual matrices are too small to solve efficiently on the GPU individually, but too big to use the batched LU decomposition to solve them all at once.

Comment: @JonathanDursi Good suggestion. Cast the final vote to close the other one. It would be great if others can retract close votes on this one.

Comment: @PavanYalamanchili: close votes are not retractible.

Comment: @talonmies I retracted mine couple of hours ago. click on close again and you can see "retract vote" or something along those lines.

Comment: Are the 1440 equations in the loop dependent on one another?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the problem *can* be converted into a tri-diagonal problem, you can use [cusparseXgtsvStridedBatch](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cusparse/index.html#topic_10_4) to the multiple problems without using a for loop. You will have to use cusparse_v2.h instead of cusparse.h for this to work.

If the problem *can not* be converted into a tri-diagonal problem, you can use routines from CULA to solve your problem. More information regarding this can be read in their [blog post](http://www.culatools.com/blog/2010/12/02/banded-solvers/). However this is a commercial library. It may also not be best suited for a band of matrix with 3 bands only.

Comment: The batched solver is a good suggestion, but I suspect that the loop is probably part of an implicit integration scheme or similar so that the solutions aren't going to be independent.

Comment: @talonmies It's hard to think of an iterative solver with an exact number of iterations.

Comment: @PavanYalamanchili: I cannot use a CULA or any commercial library as of now.

Comment: I have seen an example in CUDA5.0 sdk using cusparseScsrilu0 to get the incomplete LU factorization with 0 fill-in and no pivoting.
After this cusparseScsrsv_analysis and cusparseScsrsv_solve is used to get the solution in an iterative way.
If I use this technique for very few iteration, will my solution be close and will there be any improvement in performance.

Comment: @PavanYalamanchili: implicit Euler scheme for integrating a linear PDE. The integration is unconditionally stable, so the number of loop iterations is simply the number of integration timesteps,

Comment: @TheSeriousJoker Can you provide a pointer to the example you cite?

Comment: [cusolver](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cusolver/index.html) can be used for direct solution of sparse linear systems.  In addition, refer to the cusolver sample codes in the CUDA toolkit

Answer (score 2):

This is a fully worked example on how using LU factorization to solve sparse linear systems in CUDA.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <assert.h>

#include <cuda_runtime.h>
#include <cusparse_v2.h>

#include "Utilities.cuh"

cusparseHandle_t    handle; 

cusparseMatDescr_t  descrA      = 0;
cusparseMatDescr_t  descr_L     = 0;
cusparseMatDescr_t  descr_U     = 0;

csrilu02Info_t      info_A      = 0;
csrsv2Info_t        info_L      = 0;
csrsv2Info_t        info_U      = 0;

void                *pBuffer    = 0;

/*****************************/
/* SETUP DESCRIPTOR FUNCTION */
/*****************************/
void setUpDescriptor(cusparseMatDescr_t &descrA, cusparseMatrixType_t matrixType, cusparseIndexBase_t indexBase) {
    cusparseSafeCall(cusparseCreateMatDescr(&descrA));
    cusparseSafeCall(cusparseSetMatType(descrA, matrixType));
    cusparseSafeCall(cusparseSetMatIndexBase(descrA, indexBase));
}

/**************************************************/
/* SETUP DESCRIPTOR FUNCTION FOR LU DECOMPOSITION */
/**************************************************/
void setUpDescriptorLU(cusparseMatDescr_t &descrLU, cusparseMatrixType_t matrixType, cusparseIndexBase_t indexBase, cusparseFillMode_t fillMode, cusparseDiagType_t diagType) {
    cusparseSafeCall(cusparseCreateMatDescr(&descrLU));
    cusparseSafeCall(cusparseSetMatType(descrLU, matrixType));
    cusparseSafeCall(cusparseSetMatIndexBase(descrLU, indexBase));
    cusparseSafeCall(cusparseSetMatFillMode(descrLU, fillMode));
    cusparseSafeCall(cusparseSetMatDiagType(descrLU, diagType));
}

/**********************************************/
/* MEMORY QUERY FUNCTION FOR LU DECOMPOSITION */
/**********************************************/
void memoryQueryLU(csrilu02Info_t &info_A, csrsv2Info_t &info_L, csrsv2Info_t &info_U, cusparseHandle_t handle, const int N, const int nnz, cusparseMatDescr_t descrA, cusparseMatDescr_t descr_L,
                   cusparseMatDescr_t descr_U, double *d_A, int *d_A_RowIndices, int *d_A_ColIndices, cusparseOperation_t matrixOperation, void **pBuffer) {

    cusparseSafeCall(cusparseCreateCsrilu02Info(&info_A));
    cusparseSafeCall(cusparseCreateCsrsv2Info(&info_L));
    cusparseSafeCall(cusparseCreateCsrsv2Info(&info_U));

    int pBufferSize_M, pBufferSize_L, pBufferSize_U;
    cusparseSafeCall(cusparseDcsrilu02_bufferSize(handle, N, nnz, descrA, d_A, d_A_RowIndices, d_A_ColIndices, info_A, &pBufferSize_M));
    cusparseSafeCall(cusparseDcsrsv2_bufferSize(handle, matrixOperation, N, nnz, descr_L, d_A, d_A_RowIndices, d_A_ColIndices, info_L, &pBufferSize_L));
    cusparseSafeCall(cusparseDcsrsv2_bufferSize(handle, matrixOperation, N, nnz, descr_U, d_A, d_A_RowIndices, d_A_ColIndices, info_U, &pBufferSize_U));

    int pBufferSize = max(pBufferSize_M, max(pBufferSize_L, pBufferSize_U));
    gpuErrchk(cudaMalloc((void**)pBuffer, pBufferSize));

}

/******************************************/
/* ANALYSIS FUNCTION FOR LU DECOMPOSITION */
/******************************************/
void analysisLUDecomposition(csrilu02Info_t &info_A, csrsv2Info_t &info_L, csrsv2Info_t &info_U, cusparseHandle_t handle, const int N, const int nnz, cusparseMatDescr_t descrA, cusparseMatDescr_t descr_L,
    cusparseMatDescr_t descr_U, double *d_A, int *d_A_RowIndices, int *d_A_ColIndices, cusparseOperation_t matrixOperation, cusparseSolvePolicy_t solvePolicy1, cusparseSolvePolicy_t solvePolicy2, void *pBuffer) {

    int structural_zero;

    cusparseSafeCall(cusparseDcsrilu02_analysis(handle, N, nnz, descrA, d_A, d_A_RowIndices, d_A_ColIndices, info_A, solvePolicy1, pBuffer));
    cusparseStatus_t status = cusparseXcsrilu02_zeroPivot(handle, info_A, &structural_zero);
    if (CUSPARSE_STATUS_ZERO_PIVOT == status){ printf("A(%d,%d) is missing\n", structural_zero, structural_zero); }

    cusparseSafeCall(cusparseDcsrsv2_analysis(handle, matrixOperation, N, nnz, descr_L, d_A, d_A_RowIndices, d_A_ColIndices, info_L, solvePolicy1, pBuffer));
    cusparseSafeCall(cusparseDcsrsv2_analysis(handle, matrixOperation, N, nnz, descr_U, d_A, d_A_RowIndices, d_A_ColIndices, info_U, solvePolicy2, pBuffer));

}

/************************************************/
/* COMPUTE LU DECOMPOSITION FOR SPARSE MATRICES */
/************************************************/
void computeSparseLU(csrilu02Info_t &info_A, cusparseHandle_t handle, const int N, const int nnz, cusparseMatDescr_t descrA, double *d_A, int *d_A_RowIndices,
                     int *d_A_ColIndices, cusparseSolvePolicy_t solutionPolicy ,void *pBuffer) {

    int numerical_zero;

    cusparseSafeCall(cusparseDcsrilu02(handle, N, nnz, descrA, d_A, d_A_RowIndices, d_A_ColIndices, info_A, solutionPolicy, pBuffer));
    cusparseStatus_t status = cusparseXcsrilu02_zeroPivot(handle, info_A, &numerical_zero);
    if (CUSPARSE_STATUS_ZERO_PIVOT == status){ printf("U(%d,%d) is zero\n", numerical_zero, numerical_zero); }

}

void solveSparseLinearSystem() {


}

/********/
/* MAIN */
/********/
int main()
{
    // --- Initialize cuSPARSE
    cusparseSafeCall(cusparseCreate(&handle));

    /**************************/
    /* SETTING UP THE PROBLEM */
    /**************************/
    const int Nrows = 4;                        // --- Number of rows
    const int Ncols = 4;                        // --- Number of columns
    const int N = Nrows;

    // --- Host side dense matrix
    double *h_A_dense = (double*)malloc(Nrows * Ncols * sizeof(*h_A_dense));

    // --- Column-major ordering
    h_A_dense[0] = 0.4612f;  h_A_dense[4] = -0.0006f;   h_A_dense[8] = 0.3566f; h_A_dense[12] = 0.0f;
    h_A_dense[1] = -0.0006f; h_A_dense[5] = 0.4640f;    h_A_dense[9] = 0.0723f; h_A_dense[13] = 0.0f;
    h_A_dense[2] = 0.3566f;  h_A_dense[6] = 0.0723f;    h_A_dense[10] = 0.7543f; h_A_dense[14] = 0.0f;
    h_A_dense[3] = 0.f;      h_A_dense[7] = 0.0f;       h_A_dense[11] = 0.0f;    h_A_dense[15] = 0.1f;

    // --- Create device array and copy host array to it
    double *d_A_dense;  gpuErrchk(cudaMalloc(&d_A_dense, Nrows * Ncols * sizeof(*d_A_dense)));
    gpuErrchk(cudaMemcpy(d_A_dense, h_A_dense, Nrows * Ncols * sizeof(*d_A_dense), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice));

    // --- Allocating and defining dense host and device data vectors
    double *h_x = (double *)malloc(Nrows * sizeof(double));
    h_x[0] = 100.0;  h_x[1] = 200.0; h_x[2] = 400.0; h_x[3] = 500.0;

    double *d_x;        gpuErrchk(cudaMalloc(&d_x, Nrows * sizeof(double)));
    gpuErrchk(cudaMemcpy(d_x, h_x, Nrows * sizeof(double), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice));

    /*******************************/
    /* FROM DENSE TO SPARSE MATRIX */
    /*******************************/
    // --- Descriptor for sparse matrix A
    setUpDescriptor(descrA, CUSPARSE_MATRIX_TYPE_GENERAL, CUSPARSE_INDEX_BASE_ONE);

    int nnz = 0;                                // --- Number of nonzero elements in dense matrix
    const int lda = Nrows;                      // --- Leading dimension of dense matrix
    // --- Device side number of nonzero elements per row
    int *d_nnzPerVector;    gpuErrchk(cudaMalloc(&d_nnzPerVector, Nrows * sizeof(*d_nnzPerVector)));
    // --- Compute the number of nonzero elements per row and the total number of nonzero elements in the dense d_A_dense
    cusparseSafeCall(cusparseDnnz(handle, CUSPARSE_DIRECTION_ROW, Nrows, Ncols, descrA, d_A_dense, lda, d_nnzPerVector, &nnz));
    // --- Host side number of nonzero elements per row
    int *h_nnzPerVector = (int *)malloc(Nrows * sizeof(*h_nnzPerVector));
    gpuErrchk(cudaMemcpy(h_nnzPerVector, d_nnzPerVector, Nrows * sizeof(*h_nnzPerVector), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost));

    printf("Number of nonzero elements in dense matrix = %i\n\n", nnz);
    for (int i = 0; i < Nrows; ++i) printf("Number of nonzero elements in row %i = %i \n", i, h_nnzPerVector[i]);
    printf("\n");

    // --- Device side sparse matrix
    double *d_A;            gpuErrchk(cudaMalloc(&d_A, nnz * sizeof(*d_A)));
    int *d_A_RowIndices;    gpuErrchk(cudaMalloc(&d_A_RowIndices, (Nrows + 1) * sizeof(*d_A_RowIndices)));
    int *d_A_ColIndices;    gpuErrchk(cudaMalloc(&d_A_ColIndices, nnz * sizeof(*d_A_ColIndices)));

    cusparseSafeCall(cusparseDdense2csr(handle, Nrows, Ncols, descrA, d_A_dense, lda, d_nnzPerVector, d_A, d_A_RowIndices, d_A_ColIndices));

    // --- Host side sparse matrix
    double *h_A = (double *)malloc(nnz * sizeof(*h_A));
    int *h_A_RowIndices = (int *)malloc((Nrows + 1) * sizeof(*h_A_RowIndices));
    int *h_A_ColIndices = (int *)malloc(nnz * sizeof(*h_A_ColIndices));
    gpuErrchk(cudaMemcpy(h_A, d_A, nnz*sizeof(*h_A), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost));
    gpuErrchk(cudaMemcpy(h_A_RowIndices, d_A_RowIndices, (Nrows + 1) * sizeof(*h_A_RowIndices), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost));
    gpuErrchk(cudaMemcpy(h_A_ColIndices, d_A_ColIndices, nnz * sizeof(*h_A_ColIndices), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost));

    printf("\nOriginal matrix in CSR format\n\n");
    for (int i = 0; i < nnz; ++i) printf("A[%i] = %.0f ", i, h_A[i]); printf("\n");

    printf("\n");
    for (int i = 0; i < (Nrows + 1); ++i) printf("h_A_RowIndices[%i] = %i \n", i, h_A_RowIndices[i]); printf("\n");

    for (int i = 0; i < nnz; ++i) printf("h_A_ColIndices[%i] = %i \n", i, h_A_ColIndices[i]);

    /******************************************/
    /* STEP 1: CREATE DESCRIPTORS FOR L AND U */
    /******************************************/
    setUpDescriptorLU(descr_L, CUSPARSE_MATRIX_TYPE_GENERAL, CUSPARSE_INDEX_BASE_ONE, CUSPARSE_FILL_MODE_LOWER, CUSPARSE_DIAG_TYPE_UNIT);
    setUpDescriptorLU(descr_U, CUSPARSE_MATRIX_TYPE_GENERAL, CUSPARSE_INDEX_BASE_ONE, CUSPARSE_FILL_MODE_UPPER, CUSPARSE_DIAG_TYPE_NON_UNIT);

    /**************************************************************************************************/
    /* STEP 2: QUERY HOW MUCH MEMORY USED IN LU FACTORIZATION AND THE TWO FOLLOWING SYSTEM INVERSIONS */
    /**************************************************************************************************/
    memoryQueryLU(info_A, info_L, info_U, handle, N, nnz, descrA, descr_L, descr_U, d_A, d_A_RowIndices, d_A_ColIndices, CUSPARSE_OPERATION_NON_TRANSPOSE, &pBuffer);

    /************************************************************************************************/
    /* STEP 3: ANALYZE THE THREE PROBLEMS: LU FACTORIZATION AND THE TWO FOLLOWING SYSTEM INVERSIONS */
    /************************************************************************************************/
    analysisLUDecomposition(info_A, info_L, info_U, handle, N, nnz, descrA, descr_L, descr_U, d_A, d_A_RowIndices, d_A_ColIndices, CUSPARSE_OPERATION_NON_TRANSPOSE, CUSPARSE_SOLVE_POLICY_NO_LEVEL, 
                            CUSPARSE_SOLVE_POLICY_USE_LEVEL, pBuffer);

    /************************************/
    /* STEP 4: FACTORIZATION: A = L * U */
    /************************************/
    computeSparseLU(info_A, handle, N, nnz, descrA, d_A, d_A_RowIndices, d_A_ColIndices, CUSPARSE_SOLVE_POLICY_NO_LEVEL, pBuffer);

    /*********************/
    /* STEP 5: L * z = x */
    /*********************/
    // --- Allocating the intermediate result vector
    double *d_z;        gpuErrchk(cudaMalloc(&d_z, N * sizeof(double)));

    const double alpha = 1.;
    cusparseSafeCall(cusparseDcsrsv2_solve(handle, CUSPARSE_OPERATION_NON_TRANSPOSE, N, nnz, &alpha, descr_L, d_A, d_A_RowIndices, d_A_ColIndices, info_L, d_x, d_z, CUSPARSE_SOLVE_POLICY_NO_LEVEL, pBuffer));

    /*********************/
    /* STEP 5: U * y = z */
    /*********************/
    // --- Allocating the result vector
    double *d_y;        gpuErrchk(cudaMalloc(&d_y, Ncols * sizeof(double)));

    cusparseSafeCall(cusparseDcsrsv2_solve(handle, CUSPARSE_OPERATION_NON_TRANSPOSE, N, nnz, &alpha, descr_U, d_A, d_A_RowIndices, d_A_ColIndices, info_U, d_z, d_y, CUSPARSE_SOLVE_POLICY_USE_LEVEL, pBuffer));

    /********************************/
    /* MOVE THE RESULTS TO THE HOST */
    /********************************/
    double *h_y = (double *)malloc(Ncols * sizeof(double));
    gpuErrchk(cudaMemcpy(h_x, d_y, N * sizeof(double), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost));
    printf("\n\nFinal result\n");
    for (int k = 0; k<N; k++) printf("x[%i] = %f\n", k, h_x[k]);
}
```

Comment: This may give correct results for certain input matrix patterns, but doesn't give the correct result for general matrix patterns, because the *incomplete* LU decomposition is suitable for an iterative solution method, but not suitable for a direct solution method.  Instead cusolver may be a better option for direct solution.