# multi-stream in CUSPARSE

Tags: cuda

I am solving AX=B using Cusparse for 1440 times (A is being modified, only diagonal elements, and B is also different). I am creating handle and analysis object just once.

I am using cusparseScrsilu0().

I want to perform this operation using streams. I have tried this using one handle and creating multiple streams but didn't get any speed-up.

Please, help me out of this problem.

Comment: Seems like a lot of people are solving 1440 sparse equations using CuSparse lately.....

Comment: Yes, see also [LU factorization on GPU](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17721987/lu-factorization-on-gpu).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You expect multi-stream design can make your CUDA kernels executing concurrently. However multi-stream does not always lead to [Concurrent Kernel Execution](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#asynchronous-concurrent-execution). Kernels can be excuted concurrenly only when they fulfill certain pre-requests. One of the most important conditions is that each of your kernels occupies only a small portion of the hardware resources (SMs, texture, local mem, etc.). So if the size of your problem is large enough, then there will be no extra resources for another kernel to run concurrently.